# Return dynamic values as arguments

Tags: javascript, function, arguments

How can I pass **dynamic arguments to a function**, e.g

```
var customvar = 1; //example

  function iLike(){

      console.log("you like ... (I know how to receive the arguments!)")
  }

  function getDrink(){

       return (customvar == 1 ? ('pepsi','cola') : ('drpepper'));
  }

  iLike('peanuts', 'pizza', getDrink());

  iLike('peanuts', 'pizza', 'pepsi', 'cola'); // = result
```

How to pass **arguments from `getDrink()` correctly** - I do only do receive 'cola' but not 'pepsi'.

Comment: I guess you are taking about "return value" here (not arguments), please confirm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want `getDrink` to return an array containing `'pepsi'` and `'cola'` then the syntax is `['pepsi', 'cola']`

I'm not quite sure if that's what you wanted...

Note that that would still give you:

```
iLike('peanuts', 'pizza', ['pepsi', 'cola'])
```

Three arguments, out of which the last is an array, rather than four arguments.

If you want `iLike` to be called with four string arguments, you might want to call it like this:

```
function getDrink(){
    return (customvar == 1 ? ['pepsi','cola'] : ['drpepper']);
}

iLike.apply(this, ['peanuts', 'pizza'].concat(getDrinks()))
```

Comment: i've re-edited my question. i want to recieve getDrink() like arguments. is this possible ?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to send dynamic number of arguments, use `apply` function:

```
getDrink.apply(this, ['pepsi', 'cola']);
getDrink.apply(this, ['pepsi', 'cola', '7up']);
```

You can also use `call` function:

```
getDrink.call(this, 'pepsi', 'cola');
getDrink.call(this, 'pepsi', 'cola', '7up');
```

If you want to access all the arguments in a function u can use `arguments` array

```
function getDrink() {
var first = arguments[0]; //pepsi
var secon = arguments[1]; //cola
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/functions_and_function_scope/arguments) object for that:

```
function iLike(){
   var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments); //convert to real array
   console.log('I like '+args[0]+', '+args[1]+' and '+args[2]);
}
```

If you want to return 'pepsi' as well as 'cola' (in 1 variable) from `getDrink`, you could use an array:

```
function getDrink(){
       return (customvar == 1 ? ['pepsi','cola'] : 'drpepper');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to work with arrays, and use `apply`.

```
var customvar = 0;    

function iLike() {
    console.log(arguments);
}

function getDrink() {
    return (customvar == 1 ? ["pepsi", "cola"] : ["drpepper"]);
}

iLike.apply(this, ["peanuts", "pizza"].concat(getDrink()));
// ["peanuts", "pizza", "drpepper"]
```